# Присваивание глобальных перемененных в лямбда-функциях

Tags: python, lambda

Я бы хотел внутри лямбда функции присваивать значения глобальным переменным. Возможно ли это?

```
lambda speed: speed = sc.get()
```

Comment: Лямбды не должны иметь побочных эффектов.

Answer (score 0):

```
global_value = 1
l = lambda speed: globals().update({'global_value': speed})
# l = lambda speed: globals().__setitem__('global_value', speed)
l(42)
print(global_value) # 42
```